# C - Storing Inputted variables to different function

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that takes 5 inputted integers, and prints out asterisks in their places. I have to create a second function to pass the variables to print them out, but can only have 1 value passed to it. This is where I am getting confused with, because we have not went over arrays yet, and I think that maybe a possible way to finish it?? Anyone point me in the direction I should be headed with this?

Currently have this so far:

```
int main()
{
//Variables
int counter = 1;
int chart = 0;
//I/O section for user input
printf ("Please enter number of asterisks for 5 graphs, must be less than or equal to 50\n");
for (counter; counter <= 5; counter++)
    {
        do
        {
          printf("How long is chart %d? ", counter) ;
          scanf("%d", &chart) ;
        }while (chart > 50) ;
    }
}
```

I originally had something like below, before I had known it had to passed to a different function:

```
int main()
{
//Variables
  int chart1 ;
  int chart2 ;
  int chart3 ;
  int chart4 ;
  int chart5 ;
//I/O section for user input
    printf ("How long is chart 1? ");
    scanf("%d", &chart1 );
    if (chart1 <= 50)
    {
      printf("\nPlease enter a number less than or equal to 50") ;
    }
    else
    {
    printf ("How long is chart 2? ");
    scanf("%d", &chart2 );
    printf ("How long is chart 3? ");
    scanf("%d", &chart3 );
    printf ("How long is chart 4? ");
    scanf("%d", &chart4 );
    printf ("How long is chart 5? ");
    scanf("%d", &chart5 );
    }
//Chart 1 Print, loop, and counter
      do
      {
        printf ("1.  %d|", chart1);
        for (chart1; chart1 >0; chart1--)
        {
          printf("*");
        }
      } while(chart1 != 0);
//Chart2 Print, loop, and counter
    ....
//Chart 3 Print, loop, and counter
   ..
//Chart 4 Print, loop, and counter
   ..
//Chart 5 print, loop, and counter
    ..
}
```

Comment: could you please mark an answer to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this might be what you are looking for :

```
for (counter = 0; counter < 5; counter++) //notice changes here as well
    {
          printf("How long is chart %d? ", counter) ;
          scanf("%d", &chart) ;
          changeToAsterisk(chart);
    }
```

where your method definition can have the for loop of displaying the asterisk using the argument(not exactly but something like this ) :

```
void changeToAsterisk(int chartNumber) {
  printf ("1.  %d|", chartNumber);
  for (int i = 0; i < chartNumber; i++)
    {
     printf("*");
    }
}
```

Comment: I would prefer prefix version of increment operator

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can pass an array of integers to a function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(int arr[]);

int main()
{
    int my_array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    print_array(my_array);

    return 0;
}

void print_array(int arr[])
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```